# Fast Looping over combinations of elements from two large ditionaries of sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set, iteration, combinations

I have two very big dictionaries of sets and I want to loop over all combinations of pairs of them to calculate a "score" for each pair and store this in another object. The key in each dictionary is a unique identifier for each set. The code I am currently using is something along the lines of:

```
score_matrix = {}
for id_1, set_1 in set_dict_1:
    number_elements_1 = len(set_1)
    score_matrix[id_1] = {}
    for id_2, set_2 in set_dict_2:
        score_matrix[id_1][id_2] = float(len(set_1 & set_2)) / number_elements_1
```

I am testing this on data where `dict_1` and `dict_2` have around 25k elements. So this thing has to process around 625,000,000 combinations! Obviously I don't expect this to be done in seconds but in pure python like this it is taking too long. In fact, I don't know how long it takes because I didn't let it finish running but it was going for around 15 mins before I gave up.

I assume there is a more efficient way to try and achieve this. Any ideas? Perhaps using numpy might help but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Have you tried it with smaller amounts of data?

Comment: Will any of the sets be identical? It might be worth hashing them, and keeping the result of the comparison in a dictionary.

Comment: I have not yet tried with smaller amounts of data. I will give it a go with dicts containing 100 sets (so 10,000 combinations in total) and see how long that takes.

I don't really think any of the sets will be identical. I mean, i don't know for sure, but certainly I don't think there would be many identical sets so the number of distinct sets would still be very large.